# iOS - Ephemeral Session and UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, nsurlsession

I'd like to load a web page into a `UIWebView`, using `URLSession`.

An **ephemeral session**, indeed, because i wouldn't like to store the session if, for example, i've a login on Twitter/FB/whatever site.

So, i've a `UIWebView` named `webPage`

```
@IBOutlet var webPage: UIWebView!
```

a `UITextField`, where i can write the URL

```
@IBOutlet var urlField: UITextField!
```

Next to this text field, i've a `UIButton`, that implements this action

```
@IBAction func sendUrl(_ sender: Any) {
    let stringUrl = urlField.text
    let url = URL (string: stringUrl!)
    openPageWithSession(url: url!)
}
```

and the function `openPageWithSession`, where i use the **ephemeral session**

```
func openPageWithSession(url: URL){
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let ephemeralConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        let ephemeralSession = URLSession(configuration: ephemeralConfiguration)

        let task = ephemeralSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.webPage.loadRequest(request)
            } else {
                print("ERROR: \(error)")
            }

        }

        task.resume()

    }
```

The loading of the web page it's ok. But if i've a login on Twitter and after that i kill the app, if i reopen the app and navigate Twitter again, i'm already logged in!

Why? The ephemeral session is not invalidate after a kill?

Comment: One problem I see is that `self.webPage.loadRequest(request)` doesn't actually use the ephemeral session you created at all, it just takes the original request and loads it.

Comment: Doesn't perform the loading thanks to `task.resume()` where `task` is a `dataTask` built on the **ephemeral session**?

Comment: Instead of `self.webPage.loadRequest(request)`, you should use `self.webView.load(data!, mimeType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "", baseURL: url)`. That way you'll be using the ephemeral session you created. Otherwise you're just loading the web view normally, without the ephemeral session at all.

Comment: Great! I've to read better the doc. If you answer the question, i mark it like the correct! thank you!

Comment: As an alternative, you could use a `WKWebView` and just set the `dataStore` to `nonPersistent`.

Comment: Thanks @CleverError, but i've to use this way. `URLSession`, ephemeral, + `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the comments above.*

Instead of `self.webPage.loadRequest(request)`, you should use:

```
self.webView.load(data, mimeType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "", baseURL: url).
```

This way you'll be using the ephemeral session you created. Otherwise you're just loading the web view normally, without the ephemeral session at all.